# Nested States in Haskell

Tags: haskell, state, monads, monad-transformers, state-monad

I am trying to define a family of state machines with somewhat different kinds of states. In particular, the more "complex" state machines have states which are formed by combining the states of simpler state machines.

(This is similar to an object oriented setting where an object has several attributes which are also objects.)

Here is a simplified example of what I want to achieve.

```
data InnerState = MkInnerState { _innerVal :: Int }

data OuterState = MkOuterState { _outerTrigger :: Bool, _inner :: InnerState }

innerStateFoo :: Monad m => StateT InnerState m Int
innerStateFoo = do
  i <- _innerVal <$> get
  put $ MkInnerState (i + 1)
  return i

outerStateFoo :: Monad m =>  StateT OuterState m Int
outerStateFoo = do
  b <- _outerTrigger <$> get
  if b
    then
       undefined
       -- Here I want to "invoke" innerStateFoo
       -- which should work/mutate things
        -- "as expected" without
       -- having to know about the outerState it
       -- is wrapped in
    else
       return 666
```

More generally, I want a generalized framework where these nestings are more complex. Here is something I wish to know how to do.

```
class LegalState s

data StateLess

data StateWithTrigger where
  StateWithTrigger :: LegalState s => Bool -- if this trigger is `True`, I want to use
                                   -> s    -- this state machine
                                   -> StateWithTrigger

data CombinedState where
  CombinedState :: LegalState s => [s] -- Here is a list of state machines.
                                -> CombinedState -- The combinedstate state machine runs each of them

instance LegalState StateLess
instance LegalState StateWithTrigger
instance LegalState CombinedState

liftToTrigger :: Monad m, LegalState s => StateT s m o -> StateT StateWithTrigger m o
liftToCombine :: Monad m, LegalState s => [StateT s m o] -> StateT CombinedState m o
```

---

For context, this is what I want to achieve with this machinery:

I want to design these things called "Stream Transformers", which are basically stateful functions: They consume a token, mutate their internal state and output something. Specifically, I am interested in a class of Stream Transformers where the output is a Boolean value; we will call these "monitors".

Now, I am trying to design combinators for these objects. Some of them are:

- A `pre` combinator. Suppose that `mon` is a monitor. Then, `pre mon` is a monitor which always produces `False` after the first token is consumed and then mimicks the behaviour of `mon` as if the previous token is being inserted now. I would want to model the state of `pre mon` with `StateWithTrigger` in the example above since the new state is a boolean along with the original state.
- An `and` combinator. Suppose that `m1` and `m2` are monitors. Then, `` m1 `and` m2 `` is a monitor which feeds the token to m1, and then to m2, and then produces `True` if both of the answers were true. I would want to model the state of `` m1 `and` m2 `` with `CombinedState` in the example above since the state of both monitors must be maintained.

Comment: FYI, `_innerVal <$> get` is just `gets _innerVal` (as `gets f == liftM f get`, and `liftM` is just `fmap` specialized to monads).

Comment: Where are you getting a `StateT InnerState m Int` value in the first place in `outerStateFoo`?

Comment: @chepner in case the value b is true, I want to run the innerStateFoo

Comment: Are you comfortable with lens? This use case seems to be exactly what [`zoom`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.18.1/docs/Control-Lens-Zoom.html#v:zoom) is for.

Comment: @Carl I have seen some lenses but don't understand them very well. Maybe you can explain in an answer how to use zoom?

Comment: An observation: This entry does not contain a single question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your first question, as Carl mentioned, `zoom` from `lens` does exactly what you want.  Your code with lenses could be written like this:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Lens
import Control.Monad.State.Lazy

newtype InnerState = MkInnerState { _innerVal :: Int }
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)

data OuterState = MkOuterState
  { _outerTrigger :: Bool
  , _inner        :: InnerState
  } deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)

makeLenses ''InnerState
makeLenses ''OuterState

innerStateFoo :: Monad m => StateT InnerState m Int
innerStateFoo = do
  i <- gets _innerVal
  put $ MkInnerState (i + 1)
  return i

outerStateFoo :: Monad m =>  StateT OuterState m Int
outerStateFoo = do
  b <- gets _outerTrigger
  if b
    then zoom inner $ innerStateFoo
    else pure 666
```

Edit: While we're at it, if you're already bringing in `lens` then `innerStateFoo` can be written like so:

```
innerStateFoo :: Monad m => StateT InnerState m Int
innerStateFoo = innerVal <<+= 1
```

Answer (score 4):

> For context, this is what I want to achieve with this machinery:
>
> I want to design these things called "Stream Transformers", which are basically stateful functions: They consume a token, mutate their internal state and output something. Specifically, I am interested in a class of Stream Transformers where the output is a Boolean value; we will call these "monitors".

I think that what you want to achieve doesn't need very much machinery.

```
newtype StreamTransformer input output = StreamTransformer
  { runStreamTransformer :: input -> (output, StreamTransformer input output)
  }

type Monitor input = StreamTransformer input Bool

pre :: Monitor input -> Monitor input
pre st = StreamTransformer $ \i ->
  -- NB: the first output of the stream transformer vanishes.
  -- Is that OK? Maybe this representation doesn't fit the spec?
  let (_, st') = runStreamTransformer st i
  in  (False, st')

and :: Monitor input -> Monitor input -> Monitor input
and left right = StreamTransformer $ \i ->
  let (bleft,  mleft)  = runStreamTransformer left  i
      (bright, mright) = runStreamTransformer right i
  in  (bleft && bright, mleft `and` mright)
```

This `StreamTransformer` is not *necessarily* stateful, but admits stateful ones. You don't need to (and IMO should not! in most cases!!) reach for typeclasses in order to define these (or indeed ever! :) but that's another topic).

```
notStateful :: StreamTransformer input ()
notStateful = StreamTransformer $ \_ -> ((), notStateful)

stateful :: s -> (input -> s -> (output, s)) -> StreamTransformer input output
stateful s k = StreamTransformer $ \input ->
  let (output, s') = k input s
  in  (output, stateful s' k)

alternateBool :: Monitor anything
alternateBool = stateful True $ \_ s -> (s, not s)
```

Comment: I'd just call it pure functional programming! But I know that's not the answer you're looking for :) StreamTransformer is in fact a "Mealy machine" http://hackage.haskell.org/package/machines-0.7/docs/Data-Machine-Mealy.html

Comment: No, the first output vanishing isn't what I intended. I would like to _delay_ the first output to be the second one.

Comment: And so on so that every output is delayed by one step? That can be done.

Comment: very nice, thanks for posting! (sorry for commenting previously without heaving read the Q properly). I think the OP meant ``pre st = stateful (Nothing, st) k
  where
  k i (s,st) = let (o, st') = runStreamTransformer st i in
               ( maybe False id s , (Just o, st'))``.